# Using a GLM repeated measures in r to determine at what day do organisms raised at different temperatures become significantly different in weight?

Tags: generalized-linear-model

So I conducted an experiment that looked at the effect that a range of temperatures had on the weight of shellfish. There are 7 temperature treatments, each temperature is 1 tank (no replicates, I know its a problem). I took samples twice a week for 1 month (each sample was destructive and approximately 20 randomly sampled organisms). I am trying to find at what sampling day did the changes between treatments become statistically different from each other. My thought is to use a repeated measures general linearized model to test day against size with pH as a fixed factor that interacts with day.

so this is what my r code looks like:

glm(weight ~ Day + Temp + Day*Temp, data = Temp1

Does this make sense for what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

In a repeated measurement design you need to account for autocorrelation, so I would suggest using a mixed model.

```
library(lme4)
lmer(weight ~ Days * Temp + (1 + Days | fishID), data = temp1)
```

`Days * Temp` automatically expands to `Days : Temp + Days + Temp`.

Comment: That is a good point thank you! I was initially thinking of pooling all my organismal data together for each treatment since they are not independent of one another,  and I was concerned about psuedoreplication. Which means I would not have a subject effect, any thoughts on that?

Comment: Do you mean your shellfishes by "subject"? If `fishID` refers to your shellfishes, you can use e.g. `ranef()` to explore your random effects (which gives you - in this case - the individual differences in `weight` _from the total mean weight_ as estimated by the model). If you have time-varying predictors, you could fit a "random-effect-within-between model " (see https://strengejacke.github.io/mixed-models-snippets/random-effects-within-between-effects-model.html), which gives you estimates on the changing within- and between-subject-effects over time.

Comment: Yes I do thanks so much, I will explore these ideas further, this has been really helpful